# Abrir un menu con hover en Javascript

Tags: javascript, hover

un gusto..resulta que tengo un problema con un menu que estoy realizando, el cual en uno de sus botones me abre un div, cuando paso el mouse sobre el, pero me lo cierra cuando saco el mouse. Lo que pasa es que cuando paso del boton al div se cierra y se vuelve abrir, y lo que yo busco es que mientras este sobre el boton y sobre el div este no se cierre al menos que retire el cursor hacia otro lado, fuera tanto del boton como del div.

Aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
<a href="#" class="accionOver"> ¿A donde ir? </a>
<div class="caja">
<p>Bienvenido a la caja de accion, aqui puedes decidir que actividad realizar:
<a href="#"> ir al cine </a>
<a href="#"> ir a un restaurante </a>
</div>
```

y este es mi codigo Jquery:

```
$(".accionOver").hover(
        function(e){
        $(".caja").fadeIn("fast");
    }, 
    function(e){
        $(".caja").fadeOut("fast");
    }
);

$(".caja").hover(
    function(e){
    $(".caja").fadeIn("fast");
}, 
function(e){
    $(".caja").fadeOut("fast");
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

La idea es que apliques el cambio cuando estes en ambos lados, menu desplegable y tu anchor, por lo que tienes que tener un div externo el cual cumpla dicha función que deseas.

```html
<div class="accionOver">
  <a href="#" > ¿A donde ir? </a>
  <div class="caja">
    <p>Bienvenido a la caja de accion, aqui puedes decidir que actividad realizar:
    <a href="#"> ir al cine </a>
    <a href="#"> ir a un restaurante </a>
  </div>
</div>
```